# TravisCI and composer exec stdout

Tags: composer-php, travis-ci

When I run my test suite in travis I like to see the output.

With `php ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests` this works fine, but with with `composer exec phpunit tests` it doesn't show the output. At most you see "Script phpunit handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 255" when it fails but this doesn't tell you anything about what failed.

Why? It works on my local machine just fine.

Comment: did you founded solution? Got the same issue. The only one idea I have - composer changed behaviour. Downloaded composer version 1.2.0 - it output phpunit results correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like composer changed default verbosity level for phpunit output. Not sure, when did they do it - in composer 1.2.0 everything works ok
As a solution you can just use

```
composer exec phpunit -v
```

Comment: Looks like a miss: `composer exec phpunit -vd error_reporting=-1 tests` still doesn't show any output. Example: https://travis-ci.org/jnvsor/kint/jobs/234357653#L321